# Is $GROUP supposed to be populated by default on Linux?

Tags: linux, centos7, groups

I'm running a 3rd party install script on Centos 7.3 and its failing because $GROUP is not populated.

```
[vagrant@puppet vagrant]$ echo $USER
vagrant
[vagrant@puppet vagrant]$ echo $GROUP

[vagrant@puppet vagrant]$ groups
vagrant
```

Is $GROUP assumed to always be populated or is this the fault of the install script for assuming it is?

The script is the puppetserver start-up script.  The first script calls the second script:

First script: http://pastebin.com/g1i9qHCP
Second script: http://pastebin.com/jPZEV1Zm

Comment: Normally `$GROUP` is not assigned. Could you share the script with us? If it is too long, use pastebin or similar.

Comment: Added pastebin links to OP

Comment: I see no GROUP environment variable set anywhere. The script author has likely made a mistake.